# How to change my DAO Bean from EJB to pure CDI?

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, cdi

I want to reuse my AbstractDAO in a new project, except this time I don't want to use EJB annotations - **just CDI ones**.

**So far, I've been using it like this:**

```
public abstract class AbstractDAO<T> {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myUnit")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public AbstractDAO(Class<T> entityClass) {
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

        protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public void save(T entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
    }

    public void update(T entity) {
        entityManager.merge(entity);
    }

    public void remove(T entity) {
        entityManager.remove(entityManager.merge(entity));
    }

    public T findById(Object id) {
        return entityManager.find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> findBy(String attrName, Object attrValue) {
        // Impl here
    }

    // [...] Many more search methods
}
```

And I've been creating **a DAO for each Entity**, like this for example:

```
@Stateless
public class UserDAO extends AbstractDAO<User> {

  public UserDAO() {
    super(User.class);
  }

  public User findByUsername(String username) {
    if (username != null) {
      return super.findOneBy("username", username.toLowerCase());
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Now I would like to get rid of the @Stateless annotation. But simply replacing it with a @RequestScoped one won't work because of the **non-private constructor with no parameters** requirement of **JSR-346**

How can I refactor my DAO to a pure CDI one ?

Comment: `UserDAO` has a no-arg, non-private constructor. And `@PersistenceContext` will work for CDI beans *in a JEE environment*. Am I not getting the problem right? Have you actually tried making the `UserDAO` `@RequestScoped`? What was the error?

Comment: Just curious - what are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I found that the mix of CDI and EJB beans is confusing to many people (at least it was in my last project). Also, I read this: http://theelitegentleman.blogspot.de/2014/04/daos-as-ejbs-you-are-doing-it-wrong.html

Comment: The actual warning is "Type AbstractDAO<entity.User> (with a non-private constructor with no parameters) is not a legal type of normal scoped bean UserDAO because it cannot be proxied by the container [JSR-346 §3.15]"

Comment: Do you really need to implement the DAO yourself, why not look at a library like DeltaSpike Data, which implements a DAO with all the standard methods.

Comment: I will check it out, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two issues here: CDI beans are not transaction aware by default -unlike EJBs, so you will have to use `@Transactional` qualifier if you want to do saves/updates...
Second, your no-arg constructor: you only need to pass the entity class to your abstract class even though you also specify it as a generic argument. You can infer the actual class like this:

```
public class AbstractDAO<T> {

  private transient Class<T> entityClass;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public AbstractDAO() {
    Type generSuperCls = getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    if (generSuperCls instanceof Class) {
      generSuperCls = ((Class<?>) generSuperCls).getGenericSuperclass();
    }
    ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) generSuperCls;
    Type type = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    if (type instanceof Class) {
      this.entityClass = (Class<T>) type;
    } else if (type instanceof ParameterizedType) {
      this.entityClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) type).getRawType();
    }
  }

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager em;

  public T getById(Object id) throws ServiceException {
    return getEm().find(entityClass, id);
  }
// other methods follow
}
```

As a side note, why do you want to get rid of EJBs? [Benchmarks show](https://github.com/samolisov/spring-vs-ejb-vs-cdi-benchmark) you get better performance using pooled slsb than cdi and they together very well(every EJB beans is also a CDI bean in jee container).

Comment: I found that the mix of CDI and EJB beans is confusing to many people (at least it was in my last project). Also, I read this: http://theelitegentleman.blogspot.de/2014/04/daos-as-ejbs-you-are-doing-it-wrong.html. I did not know about the performance. I will try your solution

Comment: The post you linked is objecting against mixing business and data tier, which is not the case, if you separate DAO layer from your business services. Both EJBs and CDI beans are just container managed components, that can perform variety of roles. Internally they are very similar(if you ignore the legacy burden of remote ejbs, etc), and some servers even handle them in a common way. There is always more then one good solution to every problem:)SLSB~=@pooled&@Transactional CDI. But you are right, do what makes sense for your team, getting 10% extra perf is not worth developer frustration.

Comment: Not clear if Quarkus is an upgrade path for Wildfly apps, but if so, looks like EJB may not be supported, but CDI is, at least partially.  So, that may be one reason to drop EJB for CDI